# i keep geting the error expected identifier and i dont know what that means

Tags: roblox-studio

here is the script im working on

```
modelname="players"
function onTouched(hit)
    if not hit or not hit.Parent then return end
    local human = hit.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if human and human:IsA("Humanoid")and if game.Players:playerFromCharacter(hit.Parent).TeamColor==game.Teams:findFirstChild(modelname).TeamColor then 
       human:TakeDamage(100)
    else 
    end
end


script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

i just need someone to explain what it wants when it says there error message

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement, there are two `if` keywords. This is most likely the source of the error. To fix it, remove the second `if`.

**Fixed function**

```lua
function onTouched(hit)
    if not hit or not hit.Parent then return end
    local human = hit.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if human and human:IsA("Humanoid") and game.Players:playerFromCharacter(hit.Parent).TeamColor == game.Teams:findFirstChild(modelname).TeamColor then 
       human:TakeDamage(100)
    end
end
```

If nothing is happening in the else statement, it can be safely removed. Add it back if you have to though.

The error is basically lua expecting more than what was given, in this case a block of code defined in a then-end block.